# Cleaner property declaration

Tags: c#, language-design, syntactic-sugar

I'm working on some code for binding a Silverlight view to a presenter in the MVP pattern.  In this particular case, it's a really long exercise in doing this over and over again:

Model:

```
public bool MyBoolean
{
    get { return _myThingy.MyBoolean; }
    set { _myThingy.MyBoolean = value; }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public bool MyBoolean
{
    get { return _model.MyBoolean; }
    set { _model.MyBoolean = value; }
}
```

Clearly the presenter *could* be done away with in this example, but there are a few things that make it worth having both in this case, as not *every* property is like this, and our coding standard calls for having Model, View, and Presenter for every window/page/user control.

My real question here is, I'd really like to be able to do something like this:

Model:

```
public bool MyBoolean -> _myThingy.MyBoolean;
```

Presenter:

```
public bool MyBoolean -> _model.MyBoolean;
```

Wherein the `->` is the "bind property operator" or some similar name - essentially syntactic sugar for the first bit of code.  Is there something like this already?  If not, is there a cleaner way to do what I'm doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there something like this already? If not, is there a cleaner way to do what I'm doing?

No.  In terms of code, what you have is likely the best option.  C# does not provide this type of functionality in any feature.

However, you could use tooling to make this simpler.  For example, a Resharper template could easily make creating one of these very quick.  The second could be turned into a template that would just require typing something like (assuming "ptprop" as the keyword):

```
ptprop{TAB}bool{TAB}MyBoolean{Tab}_model{Enter}
```

This would simplify your development effort, though the code would be identical...